# In Redis, what does letter "z" in zadd, zscore mean?

Tags: hash, redis, sortedset

In Redis, I can use **sorted set**'s command: zadd,zcard, etc. But what does "z" represent?

the **set**'s command begins with "s": sadd, spop, etc. It has obvious meaning.

So how about "z" in zadd, zcard?